Minecraft 1.0 Can't craft flint and steel
So I put one flint in the top right corner and one iron bar in the bottom left corner and it wont let me craft a flint and steel. This is Minecraft version 1.0. Anyone know why this is happening? The same thing happened when I was trying to craft a book.

Until 1.7.2, the recipes had shapes:


The "History" section of wiki articles ([1] [2]) is often very useful when playing in old versions. If that is not enough, you can check when the next version was released (1.0.1) and look at the wiki pages from just before ([1] [2], except in these cases, the crafting template is broken).

Thank you so much

@PenguRoxy mark this answer as accepted.

@Hipposgrumm you are right, but that sounds a bit rude

@pinckerman Sorry, I didn't mean to come off as rude. I would've added a "please" but somehow forgot or something.

how do I do that lol

There should be a checkbox below the vote buttons on the left. The meaning of that is that this was the answer that solved the question for you. (Since it seems to be solved and this is the only answer, it would have to be this one.)

Nice when you get reputation for accepting an answer. Even more so when your answer is accepted. Question for @FabianRöling, remind me what the Crafting Template is again. Is that the UI code that says, "if there is an iron ingot on the top left of the flint, that'll result in Flint and Steel"?

"Templates" are a concept in wiki software that lets you reuse text or code without having to type it every time. The in-game concept that you described is called a "recipe".
